# Asymptotic of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma (k+n+1) \Gamma (3 k+n+1)}{\Gamma (k+2) \Gamma (3 k+2 n+2)}$ as $n\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

Let $a,b,c,d$ be fixed and in a small neighborhood of $0$, so the series $$f(n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma (a+k+n+1) \Gamma (b+3 k+n+1)}{\Gamma (c+k+2) \Gamma (d+3 k+2 n+2)}$$ converges, the title is special case $a=b=c=d=0$.

> Question: What is the leading asymptotic of $f(n)$ as $n\to \infty$,
> with general $a,b,c,d$ near $0$.

The expression of $f(n)$ is a hypergeometric series and can be converted into an integral form, then a similar analysis like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589235) should be feasible. But this approach is quite complicated, I'm looking for alternative solutions. Thank you very much.

Comment: It seems to me that dealing with an integral is the simpliest way to identify the asymptotics in many cases (though, this is only my opinion). I could only try to handle the integral; if you are looking for another approach (dealing with the series, for example) - I cannot help for sure and give up in advance :)

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you for the comment. I'm perfectly fine with an approach using integral.

Comment: By heuristic I got 
$$f(n)\sim\frac12\Gamma\left(\frac12+\frac{c+d-a-b}2\right)3^{(1+d-b+3c-3a)/2}n^{\frac32(a+b-c-d)-\frac32}\frac1{3^n}$$
WA (the free option) provides a very rough agreement, by that is not what I could expect. Could you please check from you side - to understand whether I'm running in the right direction? Meanwhile, I'll try to get deeper into this interesting problem :)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=10%5E%28149%29%283%5E%280.9%29%5CGamma%280.7%29%29%2F%282%5Ccdot3%5E%28300%29%5Ccdot300%5E%283%2F2%2B0.6%29%29    and     https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=10%5E%28149%29%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B90000%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5CGamma+%28k%2B301.1%29+%5CGamma+%283+k%2B301.2%29%7D%7B%5CGamma+%28k%2B2.3%29+%5CGamma+%283+k%2B602.4%29%7D

Comment: Also https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=10%5E%28149%29%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B90000%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5CGamma+%28k%2B301.05%29+%5CGamma+%283+k%2B301.01%29%7D%7B%5CGamma+%28k%2B2.05%29+%5CGamma+%283+k%2B602.01%29%7D and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=10%5E%28149%29%5Csqrt%7B3%5Cpi%7D%2F%282%5Ccdot3%5E%28300%29%5Ccdot300%5E%283%2F2%29%29

Answer (score 5):

First of all we note that
$$g(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\Gamma (a+k+n+1) \Gamma (b+3 k+n+1)}{\Gamma (c+k+2) \Gamma (d+3 k+2 n+2)}\ll\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{\Gamma (a+k+n+1) \Gamma (b+3 k+n+1)}{\Gamma (c+k+2) \Gamma (d+3 k+2 n+2)}=:S_n$$
at $n\to\infty$

Indeed, using the asymptotic of digamma-function, we see that
$$\frac{d}{dk}\frac{\Gamma (a+k+n+1) \Gamma (b+3 k+n+1)}{\Gamma (c+k+2) \Gamma (d+3 k+2 n+2)}$$
$$=\frac{\Gamma (a+k+n+1) \Gamma (b+3 k+n+1)}{\Gamma (c+k+2) \Gamma (d+3 k+2 n+2)}\Big(\psi(a+k+n+1)+\psi(b+3k+n+1)-\psi(c+k+2)-\psi(d+3k+2n+2)\Big)$$
is positive at $k\in[0;n]$; the function reaches its maximum at $k=n$, getting the multiplier $\big(\frac45\big)^{5n}$ in this point. We will se below that the second part of the sum is much bigger. Also, it is straightforward to confirm it by a numeric check.

Supposing $n, k\gg1$ and using the Stirling's asymptotic of gamma-function
$$S_n\sim\sum_{k=n}^\infty\sqrt{\frac{(k+n)(3k+n)}{k(3k+2n)}}\frac{(k+n)^a(3k+n)^b}{k^{c+1}(3k+2n)^{d+1}}e^{(k+n)\ln(k+n)+(3k+n)\ln(3k+n)-k\ln k-(3k+2n)\ln(3k+2n)}$$
Using the Euler-Maclauring summation formula we can switch to integration: all other terms of the summation formula provide additional suppression factors at $n, k\gg1$. Making also the substitution $k=nx$ (and in the next line the substitution $t=\frac1x$)
$$S_n\sim n^{a+b-c-d-1}\times$$
$$\int_{1}^\infty\frac{(x+1)^{a+1/2}(3x+1)^{b+1/2}}{x^{c+3/2}(3x+2)^{d+3/2}}e^{n\big((x+1)\ln(x+1)+(3x+1)\ln(3x+1)-x\ln x-(3x+2)\ln(3x+2)\big)}dx$$
It is easy to check that the integral converges at $a+b-c-d<1$. After straightforward transformations we get
$$S_n\sim n^{a+b-c-d-1}\times$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{(t+1)^{a+1/2}(3+t)^{b+1/2}}{(3+2t)^{d+3/2}}t^{c+d-a-b}e^{n\big((1/t+1)\ln(t+1)+(3/t+1)\ln(3+t)-(3/t+2)\ln(3+2t)\big)}dt$$
The function $h(t)=(1/t+1)\ln(t+1)+(3/t+1)\ln(3+t)-(3/t+2)\ln(3+2t)$ has a single maximum point at $t=0$; near this point
$$h(t)=-\ln3-\frac{t^2}{27}+\frac{4t^3}{27}+O(t^4)$$
Using the Laplace' method,
$$S_n\sim n^{a+b-c-d-1}\left(\frac13\right)^n\int_0^1\frac{(t+1)^{a+1/2}(3+t)^{b+1/2}}{(3+2t)^{d+3/2}}t^{c+d-a-b}e^{-\frac{nt^2}{27}}dt$$
We see that the main factor is indeed $\left(\frac13\right)^n\gg\Big(\big(\frac45\big)^{5}\Big)^n=\big(0.3276...\big)^n$. Performing integration and keeping only the leading at $n\to\infty$ term:
$$\boxed{\,f(n)\sim\left(\frac13\right)^nn^{\frac32(a+b-c-d-1)}3^{\frac32(c-a)+\frac12(d-b)}\frac{\sqrt3}2\Gamma\big(\frac12+\frac{c+d-a-b}2\big)\,}; \,a+b-c-d<1$$
It is straightforward to show that the next asymptotic term has an additional suppression factor $\frac1{\sqrt n}$. Using the third term in $h(t)$ it is not difficult to get the condition, when the approximation is applicable. Supposing that this term should give only small contribution,
$$\int_0^1e^{-\frac{nt^2}{27}}\left(1+\frac{4nt^3}{27}\right)dt\approx\sqrt{\frac{27}n}\left(\frac{\sqrt\pi}2+\frac{2\sqrt{27}}{\sqrt n}\right)\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\sqrt n\gg\frac{4\sqrt{27}}{\sqrt\pi}$$
It means that at least it should be $n\gg100$ - to get a sound approximation. But at $n\gg100 \,\,f(n)$ becomes very small, and WA (free option) refuses to evaluate the sum and integral accurately. That was the reason why I could not obtain a strong numeric check (with the accuracy of several percent), though roughly the result looked correct at any $n$ :)

Comment: Very nice solution! A brief glance at your steps seems fine to me, let me check it carefully afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you simplify the hypergeometric function
$$f(n)=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{4^{n-1} }\,\frac{\Gamma (n-2)}{\Gamma \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}  \,(A-1)$$ where
$$A=\,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{n-2}{3},\frac{n-1}{3},\frac
   {n}{3},n;\frac{2 n-1}{3},\frac{2n+1}{3},\frac{2 n}{3};1\right)$$ which is not the most pleasant to work.

A bit of numerical analysis shows that
$$\log\Bigg(\frac {f(n)}{4 \sqrt \pi}\Bigg)=a+b \,n +c \log(n)$$

A quick and dirty linear regression gives $(R^2=0.9999954)$

$$\begin{array}{|llll}
\hline
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} &
   \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & -1.35909 & 0.05189 & \{-1.46811,-1.25006\} \\
 b & -1.13160 & 0.00264 & \{-1.13715,-1.12605\} \\
 c & -1.16383 & 0.03442 & \{-1.23615,-1.09151\} \\
\end{array}$$

Using the $ISC$ to produce "nice" numbers
$$a \sim  -\frac{3+e^{\frac{1}{\pi }}}{5-e^{\gamma }}$$ for an absolute error of $7.33\times 10^{-8}$.

$$b \sim  -\frac{3 \left(2+\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{24}\right)\right)}{1+3 \pi }$$ for an absolute error of $1.35\times 10^{-8}$.

$$c \sim  -\frac {e-\zeta (5) } {e^{\frac{1}{e}} }$$ for an absolute error of $1.70\times 10^{-7}$.